# How to stop the scroll bar when using the loop to reach the last row with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can get 10 more rows in the table. Please let me know how to use to loop to reach the last row and stop to scroll bar.

**Summary**: Page loads 30 rows -> scroll to the Bottom -> 40 rows -> scroll to the Bottom -> 50 rows -> ... -> 60 rows -> ... -> 70 rows -> ... -> 80 rows -> ... -> 90 rows -> ... -> 100 rows -> stop scroll bar (no more item will be loaded and alert something).

**Currently I got**: Page loads 30 rows -> scroll to the Bottom -> 40 rows -> scroll to the Bottom -> nothing appears.

```
var rowCount = 100;
var temp = 30;
$("#myNewTable tr").slice(30).hide();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        if (temp <= rowCount) {
            $("#myNewTable tr").slice(0, temp + 10).show();
        }
    else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like temp is set to a solid 30.  After you show the additional 10, temp should be set to 40.  And so on.

```
if (temp <= rowCount) {
    $("#myNewTable tr").slice(0, temp + 10).show();
    temp = temp + 10;
}
```

Edit: Did you try anything like the above?

Comment: That's correct!!! and until temp is equal to `rowCount` so the scroll bar won't work anymore.

Comment: It didn't work when the temp is set to a solid 30 and it cannot change. Please give me some advice to solve this problem.

Comment: I added some to my original.  Did you try anything like that?

Comment: Thank you very much :-). This works well. I have tried it but in the loop so it might not be correct...